# Why is lxml not finding this class?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to scrape some text from a page with Python. Should be easy, but `lxml` always seems to surprise me. Here's what I've tried:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> import urllib

>>> response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.codecademy.com/username')
>>> tree = lxml.html.parse(response)
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> root.find_class('stat-count')
[]
```

I'm baffled. The following is in the html: `<span class="stat-count">27</span>` (There is a second span with the same class.) I can't imagine why the `find_class` method works this way for some elements, but not for others.

I'm open for any strategies for getting the contents of the first of these `span` tags. But I'd really like insight into the right way to do this. I'd like to think that using `lxml` would be faster and more maintainable than using regex, but I never seem to have a good experience.

Comment: It turns out that there is nothing wrong with this code, but for some reason a particular username redirects to the sign in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, provided `root = tree.getroot()`.

```
import lxml.html
import urllib

response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.codecademy.com/username')
tree = lxml.html.parse(response)
# tree.write('/tmp/test.html')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.find_class('stat-count'))
```

yields

```
[<Element span at 0xa3146bc>, <Element span at 0xa3146ec>]
```

Comment: I give up. Now I'm unable to reproduce the failing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [`beautifulsoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) a shot!

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.codecademy.com/username').read()
soup = BS(response)
points = soup.find("span",{"class":"stat-count"}).get_text()
print points
```

for the given url this prints `0` but when i use my codeacademy username it returns `90` so it works fine